# Why does comparing objects values return false?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a email checker to see if the email inputed on the front end is excactly the same email in the backend. I have managed to get both the front and back end emails but everytime i check them it return false, even though they are the same values. I am using Object.is to checck if the vaues are the same,I've also tried the typical (data.email  === user.email ) approach but it stills returns false even though, the values are the same.

```
router.get('/checkemail',(req,res)=>{
  let data = req.query;
  console.log(data)
  User.findOne({
    username: data.username,
  },function(error,user){
  if(error){
    res.status(401).send(error)
  } else if(Object.is(user.email, data.email)) {
    res.status(200).send(true)
  } else {
    res.status(401).send(false)
  }
})
  })
```

Comment: What are the values of `user.email` and `data.email`?

Comment: domdiddy125@gmail.com

Comment: Make sure there is no extra whitespace or some foreign character present.

Comment: What’s the output of a `console.log('%o %o', user.email, data.email)`?

Comment: they are exactly the same, can you run it locally?

Comment: No, we don't have access to your data, we can't run this code.

Comment: @Ry- it is 'domdiddy125@gmail.com ' 'domdiddy125@gmail.com'

Comment: @georges There is a space after the first one.

Comment: how does that affect Object.is(user.email,data.email), does whitespace matter in this case? if it does how can i remove it

Comment: @georges `Object.is()` determines if two values are the same. If there is a space in one but not in the other, then there is a difference, so they are not the same. You might take a look at [`str.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

Comment: `" abc "` is a different string to `"abc"`. Spaces do make a difference, hence why we asked for these two values.

Comment: you guys are right. I managed to fix it. thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try use trim() function on each param of the object.is ?

```
Object.is(user.email.trim(), data.email.trim())
```